# Unable to connect to Google API from server (401: Unauthorized)

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I've migrated a web application that sends push notifications to Android apps using Google Cloud Messaging from my local workstation to a server.

Connecting to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` worked perfectly from my workstation. My list of allowed IPs in my Google API project includes my server's IP (and I've triple checked it), but when I connect using the exact same API key from the server, I am always getting a `401` (unauthorized) response back from Google.

I am connecting from a Linode VPS, and when I `wget` the same URL, I can see that it is going over IPV6.  I've copied my server's IPV6 address from `http://whatismyv6.com/` and also included that in the list of allowed IPs, but still I'm still only getting `401` responses.

My guess is it's related to IPV6, so I'll go ahead and try to force connecting over IPV4- but I'm curious about whether anyone else has experienced this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. It suddenly just started working. Out of curiosity, I removed my IPV6 address, tried again and it failed. Then after adding it back, it failed a few times before started working again.

It seems that it may just take a little while for Google to accept the IPV6 address?

I guess I'll leave this question / answer though, in case anyone else experiences it. Make sure your server's IPV6 address is in the allowed list, then just go refill your coffee and try again later.